# Angular 4 project ng build --prod fail

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-cli

My Angular project is @Angular4.0.0.

Angular CLI: 1.7.4

Node: 6.9.5

I'm getting the following errors while trying to run npm install and ng build --prod.

**npm install errors**

- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY firebase@4.13.1

**ng build --prod error**

- ERROR in scripts.0cfd151de42187092cb0.bundle.js from UglifyJs undefined

Please anyone help me to resolve this problem.?

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24078

Comment: @JacopoSciampi , I'll check. Thanks for the prompt reply

Answer (score 0):

It has missing peer dependencies, install the peer dependencies yourself. for example:

`npm install bootstrap firebase`

for your problem that should be: `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0` `npm install --save firebase@4.13.1`

Comment: I installed bootstrap and firebase relevant versions when the issue occurred, using the commands that you have mentioned. but error was same. Is there another way to add this missing peer dependencies ? .
Thanks for the reply.

Comment: As far as I know, peer dependencies can only be added manually by doing `npm install ###`. Try reinstalling the said peer dependencies, and do an `npm install --verbose`.